# Enable network bridging on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, iptables, network-bridge, ebtables

I'm struggling to get a network bridge working on a Ubuntu server in a fairly simple set up (I thought). To do some firewall lab stuff I need three machines set up like this:

```
ALICE (eth0) ----> (eth0) WILLY (eth1) -----> (eth0) BOB
```

Willy shall be a bridge and take every network packet it gets on eth0 and pass it to eth1 (and vis versa).

Therefore I have set up Alice and Bob with static IP addresses (Alice has 10.0.0.2; Bob has 10.0.0.3).

On Willy I installed the bridge_utils package and modified /etc/network/interfaces to look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
 iface br0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

  bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

Additionally kernel module br_netfilter is loaded via

```
modprobe br_netfilter
```

I can successfully ping from ALICE to WILLY. I can NOT ping from BOB to WILLY and not from ALICE to BOB (and vis versa).

I tried everything from this troubeshooting guide ( http://www.microhowto.info/troubleshooting/troubleshooting_ethernet_bridging_on_linux.html ) and all those tests passed. Especially I see on WILLY the MAC addresses from ALICE and BOB when I do

```
brctl showmacs br0
```

So obviously the network packets arrive at WILLY, but can cross the bridge for whatever reason.

Any idea's what I missing here to get this working ? Can't believe that its that complex, so I must be missing something fundamentally.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As it might be important: All three machines are running as a VM under Windows 10 Hyper-V. I supsect that the virtual network switch is not supporting promiscious mode.

Comment: Another interesting observation is that tshark -i br0 run on WILLY shows ARP requests from both, ALICE and BOB. So obviously the packets arrive at WILLY and are "just" not passed across to the other side.

Comment: And I tried the same set up on MacOS using Virtualbox. Unfortunately the very same problem.